# How to detect dragboard's element ouside of stage?

Tags: javafx

I working with tabpane. I want to make the tabs detachable. The problem might is the dragboard.

I tried to use MouseRelease event on the tab's graphic to detect its position but its only work when I remove the drag events:

```
graphic.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
            Point2D mouseLoc = new Point2D(e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
            Window window = tabPane.getScene().getWindow();
            Rectangle2D windowBounds = new Rectangle2D(window.getX(), window.getY(), window.getWidth(), window.getHeight());
            if(!windowBounds.contains(mouseLoc)){
                System.out.println("new stage");
            }
        });
```

My drag events are working perfectly. I use this method to add handlers to the tabs:

```
public void addDragHandlers(Tab tab) {
        javafx.scene.control.Label label = new javafx.scene.control.Label(tab.getText(), tab.getGraphic());
        if (tab.getText() != null && !tab.getText().isEmpty()) {
            tab.setText(null);
            tab.setGraphic(label);
        }

        Node graphic = tab.getGraphic();
        graphic.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
            Point2D mouseLoc = new Point2D(e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
            Window window = tabPane.getScene().getWindow();
            Rectangle2D windowBounds = new Rectangle2D(window.getX(), window.getY(), window.getWidth(), window.getHeight());
            if(!windowBounds.contains(mouseLoc)){
                System.out.println("new stage");
            }
        });

        graphic.setOnDragDetected(e -> {
            Dragboard dragboard = graphic.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putString(draggingID);
            dragboard.setContent(content);
            dragboard.setDragView(graphic.snapshot(null, null));
            currentDraggingTab = tab;
        });

        graphic.setOnDragOver(e -> {
            if (draggingID.equals(e.getDragboard().getString()) &&
                    currentDraggingTab != null &&
                    currentDraggingTab.getGraphic() != graphic) {
                e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
            }
        });

        graphic.setOnDragDropped(e -> {
            if (draggingID.equals(e.getDragboard().getString()) &&
                    currentDraggingTab != null &&
                    currentDraggingTab.getGraphic() != graphic) {
                int index = tab.getTabPane().getTabs().indexOf(tab);
                currentDraggingTab.getTabPane().getTabs().remove(currentDraggingTab);
                tab.getTabPane().getTabs().add(index, currentDraggingTab);
                currentDraggingTab.getTabPane().getSelectionModel().select(currentDraggingTab);
            }
        });

        graphic.setOnDragDone(e -> currentDraggingTab = null);
    }
```

How can I implement the detach feature inside the drag handler?

Thanks for the help and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Have you looked at this tutorial? https://berry120.blogspot.com/2014/01/draggable-and-detachable-tabs-in-javafx.html

Comment: @trilogy this tutorial uses mouse event. Dragevent is blocking mouse events for a reason. But as I wrote Its works with mouse event, but I need the drag events for the position change